# retrieve autonumber from ms access to a strongly typed database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, identity, autonumber

I am using VS2010/VB.NET/MS Access 2007

I had added a database from ms access to the vb.net application (strongly typed)
that table contains an autonumber field.

I made a button to add new row and another one to save the row the problem is that I want to get the last autonumber from the database so that I can save the row.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `SELECT @@IDENTITY` to fetch last inserted identity value.